# Unknow table in field list ao realizar select + sum

Tags: mysql, select

Estou tentando realizar a soma de valores de varias tabelas diferentes, tentei de duas formas:

Sem citar o nome do banco de dados:

```
SELECT SUM(animais_adocao.animal_pendente + animais_encontrados.animal_pendente + animais_perdidos.animal_pendente);
```

E também citando o nome do banco de dados:

```
SELECT SUM(cademeupet.animais_adocao.animal_pendente + cademeupet.animais_encontrados.animal_pendente + cademeuppet.animais_perdidos.animal_pendente)
```

Em ambos os casos é retornado:

Unknow table in field list, como podem observar na imagem, a coluna tem esse nome e o banco também, estou esquecendo de algo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sum não soma as colunas, soma as linhas, se quiser somar colunas use só o +

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir efetuar a soma é necessário identificar as tabelas de origem de cada campo que está a utilizar.

---

Neste caso seria algo deste género (sem conhecer a estrutura das duas tabelas mas partindo do princípio que todas têm um campo `ID` que identifica o animal):

```
SELECT      SUM(aa.animal_pendente + ae.animal_pendente + ap.animal_pendente) AS soma
FROM        animais_adocao      aa
LEFT JOIN   animais_encontrados ae ON ae.id_animal = aa.id_animal
LEFT JOIN   animais_perdidos    ap ON ap.id_animal = aa.id_animal
```